# Cómo colocar una clase con jQuery al principio de las otras clases

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="clase1 clase2 clase3 clase4 clase5"></div>
```

Quiero crear una clase0 y que se coloque antes de la clase1, pero al crearlo con jQuery, ésta se agrega al final

```
$('.clase1').addClass('clase0');
```

resultado:

```
<div class="clase1 clase2 clase3 clase4 clase5 clase0"></div>
```

¿cómo hacer que se agregue antes de la clase1, es decir, así:

```
<div class="clase0 clase1 clase2 clase3 clase4 clase5"></div>
```

Comment: En este [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461853/jquery-addclass-to-first-position-of-multiple-classes) revisa la respuesta de **John K.** es una sola línea lo resuelve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma es:

- Recoger las clases existentes.
- Concatenar la nueva clasea al principio.
- Eliminar las clases antiguas.
- Y añadir el nuevo string con las clases.

Un ejemplo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
   var miclase =$('#midiv').attr('class');


   miclase = 'clase0 '+miclase;
   $('#midiv').removeClass();
   $('#midiv').addClass(miclase);

   console.log(miclase);

   });
</script>

<div  id="midiv" class="clase1">
aa
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, veo que con ésto se pueden agregar las clases que queramos al inicio